# (XML - XSD) validation failed when Tags are swapped inside Main Tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

I have an XML file and an XSD file to validate.

**XML File:**

```
<UC4Execution>
        <Script>JOB_NAME</Script>

        <UC4 Server="UC4.com" Client="123" UserId="123" Password="*****" >
        </UC4 >

</UC4Execution>
```

If I bring  first then  down, validation fails.

**I want the tags be flexible inside a main Tag. How should i manage / validate it**

**XSD File :**

```
        <xs:element name="UC4Execution">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element name="Script" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="UC4" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="Client" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow the order `Script, UC4` as well as `UC4, Script` then use `xs:all` instead of `xs:sequence`.

Comment: You beat me by a bit but I had my answer ready offline, so I posted it too. +1 to you for being first.

Answer (score 1):

**If you use `xs:all` rather than `xs:sequence`, the children of `UC4Execution` will not have a required order:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UC4Execution">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Script" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="UC4" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Client" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**So both this XML document instance,**

```
<UC4Execution>
  <Script>JOB_NAME</Script>
  <UC4 Server="UC4.com" Client="123" UserId="123" Password="*****" />
</UC4Execution>
```

**and this one:**

```
<UC4Execution>
  <UC4 Server="UC4.com" Client="123" UserId="123" Password="*****" />
  <Script>JOB_NAME</Script>
</UC4Execution>
```

**will be valid.**